# How can I install bridge-util on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, macports, bridge, fink

I want to install the bridge-utils package on my Mac OS X system. How can I do that? I can't find `bridge-utils` in Fink or MacPorts.

Comment: Don't forget to link your StackOverflow and SuperUser accounts so you can take control of this question now that it's been migrated.

Answer (score 4):

`bridge-utils` is very specific to Linux. It's the way to administer the Linux kernel's specific bridging capabilities, and only applies to Linux, not other Unix-like OSes.

Mac OS X's "Darwin" Unix layer is based on BSD (mostly FreeBSD, with some pieces borrowed from the other BSDs). In BSD-style OSes, you create bridge interfaces with `ifconfig(8)`.

Unfortunately, as of Mac OS X v10.6.x "Snow Leopard", Mac OS X does not have a bridge facility built into the kernel, so you can't use `ifconfig` to set up bridging on Mac OS X.

You might be interested in looking at the developer betas of Mac OS X 10.7 "Lion".